# Validating contact number in php form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to validate a contact number in this form (555)555-5555
but it won't work I don't know what is the problem. If I leave it blank it will print the line 
"Please fill out your contact number." but if I enter any number not in the specified from. It won't print the error line. Can some one tell me what is the problem?
Thank you.

```
if (!preg_match( "/^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/",($_POST['pcnumber'])) && (!empty($_POST['pcnumber']) ))
        {
            $msg = "pcnumber: $_POST[pcnumber] ";

        }
        else
        {
            $pcnumber = NULL;
            echo "Please fill out your contact number.";
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no white spaces etc. around / inside the number you post? Your code should match '(555)555-5555'.

Comment: `but if I enter any number not in the specified from. It won't print the error line` -- what error line?

Comment: @putvande yes, I've tried every possible input.

Comment: Looks fine to me; post the error? (p.s. you should have the empty check first, not second)

Comment: @rybo111 "Please fill put your contact number"

Comment: @dave I've tried both ways

Comment: Using if(!preg_match()) will ONLY work if there is an error which is not the same as no matches. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I don;t see the point of checking for empty? If it is empty it will not match either.

Comment: @putvande I know but the thing is even if I removed is empty. It won't work as I want to.

Comment: Well.. just remove the `!` in front of your preg_match as mentioned below should do the trick.